# How to approximate the condition number of a matrix using its component

Tags: linear-algebra, condition-number

Given a psd matrix $H=[A, B; B^\top, C]$. I can find bounds for singular values and the norm for $A, B, C$. How can I construct a bound for the condition number of $H$? I have tried using interlacing theorem but it doesn't work.

Comment: The interlacing theorem gives you that $\kappa(H) \geq \kappa(A)$ and $\kappa(H) \geq \kappa(C)$, but I don't think you can get any upper bounds for the condition number of $H$

Comment: Note that in principle, you need some restriction on $A,B,C$ in order to prevent the situation where $A$ and $C$ are invertible but $H$ is not

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hi Ben, thank you for the comment. In my problem, both A, B, C are singular. I care for the smallest non-zero singular values. I can bound their kappa, smallest and largest singular values. I agree the interlacing theorem does not give me the desired upper bound. 

Regarding the largest singular values of H, I can use the following inequality
\begin{align}
\lVert H\rVert_2 \leq \lVert [\lVert A\rVert_2,\lVert B\rVert_2;\lVert B\rVert_2,\lVert C\rVert_2]\rVert_2 
\end{align}

Comment: @BenGrossmann But I'm stuck on the non-zero smallest singular values of $H$. Moreover, I can also compute $tr(H), tr(H^2)$. Do you think given all the pieces, we can bound the smallest non-zero singular values of $H$?